# How do I write an XML Schema to allow/impose elements to occur one time in any order?

Tags: xml, xsd

The XML has a parent element `parent`, which has to contain 10 child elements: `child1` to `child10` in any order, but exactly one time.

As an alternative, the `parent` element can optionally contain `child11` to `child20` instead of `child1` to `child10`.

```
<parent><child1/><child4/> ... <child2/></parent> OK
<parent><child15/>...<child20/></parent> OK
<parent><child1/><child2/></parent> BAD, missing childs
<parent><child1/>...<child11/></parent> BAD: child11 shall never be with child1
<parent><child1/><child1/></parent> BAD: childs shall not be repeated
```

This is my schema definition attempt so far:

```
<xs:complexType name="parent">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="child2" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="child11" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="child12" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Why can `child1` not be with `child11` (example 4) yet `child5` can be with `child20` (example 2)?

Comment: @kjhughes good spot I hadn't noticed that, I assume it's a typo

Comment: Yes and sorry, it is solved now

Comment: It seem a very common/useful XSD use case, why this is not part of the scheme language? Am I making a wrong use of XML?

Comment: No what you're asking for is perfectly reasonable. It's a weak area of XML Schema language. XML Schema emphasizes sequential content a lot (for example, with complex type inheritance you can only append to base type contents sequentially). This does make life difficult for data where the order isn't important in XML formats that are intended to be (to some degree) readable and writable by humans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML Schema 1.0 doesn't have a direct solution to your problem.

What you'd want, is the following (replacing the `xs:sequence` with `xs:all`), but *this isn't valid XML Schema language*:

```
<xs:complexType name="parent">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="child2" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <!-- ... -->
        </xs:all>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="child11" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="child12" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <!-- ... -->
        </xs:all>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

The problem is that `xs:choice` allows nesting of `xs:sequence` and `xs:choice` compositors, but not `xs:all`.

There are five possibilities I see:

1. Use the schema in your question, which uses `xs:sequence` instead of `xs:all`, but use an XSL transformation to re-order as per the schema before validation.
2. If XML Schema 1.1 is an option, you may be able to define a more lax schema (i.e. one that doesn't enforce all your rules, but accepts all valid input), but get the extra checking with `xs:assert`.
3. Alternatively define a more lax schema, but do the extra checking in your own program, after the schema validation step.
4. Restructure the schema so that the two groups of related elements are nested under another element, so that you can use `xs:choice`.
5. Define `parent` as an abstract type, define derived types for the two choices of content models, and use `xsi:type` to specify which one is being used in the XML documents.

Both of the latter 2 options require changing the XML format unfortunately.

---

This is how your schema might look if you can add an extra level to the element nesting:

```
<xs:complexType name="option1">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="child2" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="option2">
    <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="child11" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="child12" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="parent">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="option1" type="option1"/>
        <xs:element name="option2" type="option2"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

---

This is how your schema might look if you use type substitution:

```
<xs:complexType name="parent" abstract="true">
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="parent_option1">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="parent">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="child2" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <!-- ... -->
            </xs:all>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="parent_option2">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="parent">
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="child11" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="child12" type="xs:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <!-- ... -->
            </xs:all>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="parent" type="parent"/>
```

An XML instance document that uses this approach would look like the following for your first group of elements (note the use of `xsi:type` to specify which group has been selected):

```
<parent
    xmlns="Your namespace here"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:type="parent_option1">

    <child2>2</child2>
    <child1>1</child1>
    <!-- ... -->

</parent>
```

And for the second group:

```
<parent
    xmlns="Your namespace here"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:type="parent_option2">

    <child11>11</child11>
    <child12>12</child12>
    <!-- ... -->

</parent>
```